# ggplot2 add geom_text on geom_col layer with labels data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, geom-text

I have a bar plot with `position = fill` to show proportions with 2 colors on the same column. I'm trying to add a `geom_text` layer on this graph to show ho many genes out of the total genes are making the plotted proportion (e.g. `Condition == "UT"`, `Keyword = "Zinc"`, 3 up 2 down -> proportions 0.6:0.4 of 5 zinc-related genes (Nb_Keyword) out of 131 DE genes in this condition (Nb_Tot) label is then 5 / 131.

I have this code for the plot and ggplot 2 uses twice the Nb_Keyword and Nb_Tot data to make up the label since there are here twice, once with `Direction == "Down"` and once with `Direction == "Up"`.

Alternatively I tried to use a specific data frame for the `aes` in `geom_text`, df_labels, which has half the number of rows of the data frame used for the bar plot. This generates an error because the data of `geom_text()`'s `aes` layer is not the same length as the bar plot data.

I did not manage to get the plot I want with `annotate()` neither. What is the right strategy to do what I want to do?

Thank you for your help!
Daniel[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

### reconstitute df3
condition <- rep(c("UT", "STV", "AA"), each = 4, times = 2)
keyword <- rep(c("Ribosome", "Zinc", "Predicted_gene", "Pseudogene"), times = 6)
nb_keyword <- rep(c(7,5,9,1,6,0,2,1,18,9,30,12), times = 2)
length(nb_keyword)
nb_tot <- rep(c(131,75,383), each = 4, times = 2)
direction <- rep(c("Down", "Up"), each = 12)
proportion <- c(5,2,6,1,1,0,2,0,6,0,21,6,2,3,4,0,5,0,0,1,12,9,9,6)

df3 <- data.frame(condition, keyword, nb_keyword, nb_tot, direction, proportion)
names(df3) <- gsub("(^|[_[:space:]])([[:alpha:]])", "\\1\\U\\2", names(df3), perl = TRUE)

df3$Condition <- ordered(df3$Condition, levels = c("UT", "STV", "AA"))
df3$Direction <- ordered(df3$Direction, levels = c("Up", "Down"))

df_labels <- df3[c(1:12), c("Condition","Keyword", "Nb_Keyword", "Nb_Tot")]

color_vector <- c(Up = "#2CA913", Down = "#DB0F0F")

# plot
p2 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x = Condition, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Direction), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_vector) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,hjust = 1, vjust=0.2)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Keyword)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = Condition, label = paste(Nb_Keyword, "/",Nb_Tot)), angle = 90)

p2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `aes` of `geom_text`, you cannot use the inherited `y` value, otherwise the labels would be according to the position in the `Proportion` column. Instead, you should set `geom_text(aes(y))` to a value close to 0. The `hjust = 0` argument is to left-align (in this case, bottom-align) the text.

**EDIT: Thanks @stefan for improving my answer by adding the `check_overlap = TRUE` argument to avoid overlapping labels.**

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df3, aes(x = Condition, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Direction), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_vector) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,hjust = 1, vjust=0.2)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Keyword)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0.05, label = paste(Nb_Keyword, "/",Nb_Tot)), angle = 90, hjust = 0, check_overlap = T)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Just a remark: For a cleaner look you could add `check_overlap = TRUE` to `geom_text` to get rid of the duplicated and overlapping (overplotted) labels.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not hear about this great `check_overlap` argument  in the ggplot2 courses I took.

Comment: @benson23 got the markdown formatting, I am curently learning about it. Thanks for updating the question text above